# Getting followers from Twitter API via json results nothing in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I'm trying to include list of my followers on my site. Here's my code:

```
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/followers.json?screen_name=username',function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

However, nothing happens. No errors, other js still works, just this doesn't work. What is wrong?

Martti Laine

Ps. I'm using jQuery for this, as page loads faster, when not using php. Content is shown faster.

Comment: Have you looked with Firebug or a similar tool to inspect the response you're getting back from Twitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger JSONP by adding this to the end of your URL: `&callback=?`, like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/followers.json?screen_name=username&callback=?',function(data){
    alert(data);
});​
```

[You can see it getting a response here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nVGSg/).  Without doing this it's attempting to make an XmlHttpRequest fetch of the data, which is blocked by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).